# How do I add a column to my CSV in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm pulling AD user details into a CSV.  The code below works exactly as expected and needed:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$GADU_Properties = @(
'Enabled',
'DisplayName',
'Description',
'EmailAddress',
'Office',
'StreetAddress',
'City',
'State',
'PostalCode',
'SamAccountName',
'Title',
'Department',
'Company',
'msExchRemoteRecipientType',
'CanonicalName'
)

$OUs = @(
'OU=FirstOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=SecondOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=ThirdOU,DC=Domain,DC=com'
)

ForEach ($OU in $OUs){
    $OU_Users = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -eq "Users"' -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Properties Name,DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DistinguishedName | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName
    ForEach ($OU_User in $OU_Users){
        $Users += Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $GADU_Properties -SearchBase $OU_User.DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select-Object $GADU_Properties
    }
}

$Users | Export-Csv -Path P:\AD_UserReport.csv -NoTypeInformation

$GADU_Properties = $null
$OUs = $null
$OU = $null
$OU_Users = $null
$OU_User = $null
$Users = $null
```

From here I have 2 challenges:

First, I would like to add a column to the CSV for $OU_User so there can be some filtering done by OU on the resulting spreadsheet.

Some things I've tried:

```
$Users += (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $GADU_Properties -SearchBase $OU_User.DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select-Object $GADU_Properties) + $OU_User.DistinguishedName
```

Results in error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At File.ps1:30 char:9
+         $Users += (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $GADU_Properties  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I've done some searching around on the error and found https://9to5it.com/using-psobject-store-data-powershell/ which seems to be leading me down the right path, though I don't understand it, really.

I've tried modifying the script as follows & moved a few things around a few times.  Below is the modified code, and I feel like I'm getting close but I'm still missing the mark.  I now have the $OU_User data in the CSV where I would expect it in the last column with no script errors.  The column headers match what I've put into $UserDetails = [PSCustomObject]

However it does not result in a line for each user per OU, and the data for most cells is System.Object[]

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Properties =
@(
'Enabled',
'DisplayName',
'Description',
'EmailAddress',
'Office',
'StreetAddress',
'City',
'State',
'PostalCode',
'SamAccountName',
#'UserPrincipalName',
'Title',
'Department',
'Company',
#'mailNickname',
'msExchRemoteRecipientType',
'CanonicalName'
)

$OUs = @(
'OU=FirstOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=SecondOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=ThirdOU,DC=Domain,DC=com'
)

$Users = @()

ForEach ($OU in $OUs){
    $OU_Users = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -eq "Users"' -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Properties Name,DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DistinguishedName | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName
    ForEach ($OU_User in $OU_Users){
        $User = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $Properties -SearchBase $OU_User.DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select-Object $Properties

        $UserDetails = [PSCustomObject] @{
            IsEnabled = $User.Enabled
            Name = $User.DisplayName
            Note = $User.Description
            Email = $User.EmailAddress
            Office = $User.Office
            Street = $User.StreetAddress
            City = $User.City
            State = $User.State
            Zip = $User.PostalCode
            Username = $User.SamAccountName
            Position = $User.Title
            Dept = $User.Department
            Company = $User.Company
            Mailbox = $User.msExchRemoteRecipientType
            CN = $User.CanonicalName
            ADOU = $OU_User.DistinguishedName
        }
        $Users += $UserDetails
    }
}

$Users | Export-Csv -Path P:\AD_UserReport.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Properties = $null
$OUs = $null
$OU = $null
$OU_Users = $null
$OU_User = $null
$Users = $null
$User = $null
$UserDetails = $null
```

As you might expect, I'm very new to arrays in general and their manipulation in PowerShell.  I've seen several examples of how to fix my script when it relates to the original error I'm seeing but I can't seem to wrap my head around them as it relates to what I'm trying to do.

Any advice?

The second challenge I mentioned would be to detect if there's a value for $_.msExchRemoteRecipientType and replace the data in the CSV to TRUE if there's a value, FALSE if there's not (showing if the user has an Exchange Online mailbox).  I'll tackle that at some point - not sure how, but it is on the list.  If anyone has pointers to that effect as well, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I dont think there is a direct way to add a column, but you could create a function to rewrite the csv as a `PSCustomObject` and add a column from there. Another way is to manually add a column to the csv file

Comment: If you want one row per OU, then you will need to join all of the values of a specific property of `$user`, effectively making a single string. The reason is that `$user` is likely going to be a collection of users. If you export a property that is an array to csv, it will just give you its type name rather than the data (calls `ToString()`). If you want one row per user but include the user OU, then you need another `foreach` loop --> `foreach ($item in $user) { $userdetails = ... }`.

Comment: You will have the same issue with `msExchRemoteRecipientType` since `$user` is going to be a collection. If you process each object within `$user` like `foreach ($item in $user) {}`, then you can simply use `[bool]$item.msExchRemoteRecipientType` to get `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to get one user per row in your CSV output (untested):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Properties =
@(
'Enabled',
'DisplayName',
'Description',
'EmailAddress',
'Office',
'StreetAddress',
'City',
'State',
'PostalCode',
'SamAccountName',
'UserPrincipalName',
'Title',
'Department',
'Company',
'mailNickname',
'msExchRemoteRecipientType',
'CanonicalName'
)

$OUs = @(
'OU=FirstOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=SecondOU,DC=Domain,DC=com',
'OU=ThirdOU,DC=Domain,DC=com'
)

$AllUsers = ForEach ($OU in $OUs){
    $OU_Users = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -eq "Users"' -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope Subtree -Properties Name,DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DistinguishedName | Select-Object Name,DistinguishedName
    ForEach ($OU_User in $OU_Users) {
        $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $Properties -SearchBase $OU_User.DistinguishedName | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select-Object $Properties
        Foreach ($user in $users) {
            $UserDetails = [PSCustomObject] @{
                IsEnabled = $User.Enabled
                Name = $User.DisplayName
                Note = $User.Description
                Email = $User.EmailAddress
                Office = $User.Office
                Street = $User.StreetAddress
                City = $User.City
                State = $User.State
                Zip = $User.PostalCode
                Username = $User.SamAccountName
                Position = $User.Title
                Dept = $User.Department
                Company = $User.Company
                Mailbox = [bool]$User.msExchRemoteRecipientType
                CN = $User.CanonicalName
                ADOU = $OU_User.DistinguishedName
            }
        $UserDetails
    }
}

$AllUsers | Export-Csv -Path P:\AD_UserReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want one row per OU, then you will need to join all of the values of a specific property of `$users`, effectively making a single string per property. The reason is that `$users` is likely going to be a collection of users. If you export a property that is an array to csv, it will just give you its type name rather than the data (calls `property.ToString()`). If you want one row per user but include the user OU, then you need another `foreach` loop --> `foreach ($user in $users) { $userdetails = ... }`.

You will have the same issue with `msExchRemoteRecipientType` since `$users` is going to be a collection. If you process each object within `$users` like `foreach ($user in $users) {}`, then you can simply use `[bool]$user.msExchRemoteRecipientType` to get `True` or `False`.